# Converting numeric date column into date and time in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, alter

I'm currently using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 and the database was created a long time ago.  The person that created it made Date into a numeric value and also GMT Time meaning that it is 4 hours ahead of the actual time, thus forcing a -4 Hour function somewhere in the query.  What I am interested is ONLY the data from the 4 days before the current day after the 4 hour conversion with the correct Date and Time format.

Columns:
Date(numeric(17,9), not null)
Parms(nvarchar(2000), null)
... etc.

```
   Right now my query is:
   -----
   SELECT ItemId, DATE,
   SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) +' Was removed from:' AS RemovalPath,
   [OBJECT] AS [MOVE LIST]
   FROM JnlList
   where UserCode = 'Automation' AND ListType = 'M'
   Order by Date DESC, RemovalPath DESC;
   -----
   1 sample row output for my query out of 385 rows is:
   -----
   ItemId: 9393
   Date: 20130627.180846113
   RemovalPath: V77963 Was Removed From:
   MOVE LIST: M-002411
   -----
   REQUIRED OUTPUT:
   ItemId: 9393
   Date: 2013-06-27
   Time: 2:08:46
   RemovalPath: V77963 Was Removed From:
   MOVE LIST: M-002411
   -----
```

Can anyone make an alterations to my query to get the required output?  That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this question any different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368654/altering-data-display-in-sql-query?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, I have fixed the column problem so I wanted to delete the previous one and post a new question only concerned with the Date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
                             SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
                             SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
                             SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
                             RIGHT([Date],3)) [Date],
            ItemId,
            Parms,
            [OBJECT]
    FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
                    Parms,
                    [OBJECT]
            FROM YourTable
            WEHRE UserCode = 'Automation' AND ListType = 'M') A
)
SELECT  ItemId,
        CONVERT(DATE,[Date]) [Date],
        CONVERT(TIME(0),[Date]) [Time],
        SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) +' Was removed from:' RemovalPath,
        [OBJECT] [MOVE LIST]
FROM CTE
WHERE [Date] >= CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @omarK Yes, just updated it. But, really, this are pretty easy to spot, you should try modifying the code just a little

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'ItemId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'Parms'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Invalid column name 'OBJECT'.

Comment: I'm not sure why its saying these columns are invalid.

Comment: it does not but you removed the UserCode requirement from the query and when I inserted it back in, it gave me an error.

Comment: and also can you explain the significance behind "with cte as" at the beginning?  What does that do?

Comment: @omarK Ok, added those filters to the answer. I'm using a "Common Table Expression" instead of a derived table to make the code more readable. Here is a link to the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Actually one last concern, is it possible for you to remove all the microsoft seconds in the Time?  Instead of 18:08:46:1130000 it should be displaying 18:08:46.

Comment: @omarK Ok, done. (By the way, those are not *microsoft* seconds)

Comment: I meant to say micro seconds*. I'm not sure why their still appearing even with your new code.

Comment: I meant to say micro seconds*.

Comment: @omarK Not sure either. Are you really using `CONVERT(TIME(0),[Date])`?

Comment: I'm using the code that you put up there ^ after you edited.  It's just annoying how this person made date a numeric value on the entire database making it difficult in making any clear representation of date and time to the end user.

Comment: @omarK Weird, it should show what you want. Then try `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[Date],108)`

Comment: It gives me this error: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

Comment: @omarK What?, are you using that code on the **last** `SELECT`?, there is no `NUMERIC` column there

Comment: Hi Lamak, the microseconds have been trimmed.  However I have just noticed that the time has not been adjusted 4 hours behind in the output.

Comment: @omarK please look into [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.100).aspx). The answer solves the crux of the problem; surely you can adjust the 4 hours yourself?

Comment: @omarK you should also look up [scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, I'm still a learning programmer and I wasn't sure how the syntax would look like.

Comment: @omarK that is fine, but sometimes it is best to learn by reading the documentation, not by repeatedly asking someone who has already solved your problem to keep spoon-feeding you just a little bit more.

Comment: @Aaronbertrand is it possible for you to show me what would need to be changed in the DATEADD? Or is that too  much to ask?

Comment: @omarK You need to use `DATEADD(HOUR,-4,Column)` on the last `SELECT` on the columns `[Date]`, `[Time]` and on the `[Date]` column on the `WHERE`

Comment: @omarK on its own it wouldn't be, but look at this comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT ItemId,
DATEADD(HH, -4, CONVERT(DATETIME, substring(DATE, 1, 4) + '-' + substring(DATE, 5, 2) + '-' + substring(DATE, 7, 2) + ' ' + substring(DATE, 10, 2) + ':' + substring(DATE, 12, 2) + ':' + substring(DATE, 14, 2) + '.' + substring(DATE, 16, 3))),
SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) +' Was removed from:' AS RemovalPath,
[OBJECT] AS [MOVE LIST]
FROM JnlList
where UserCode = 'Automation' AND ListType = 'M'
AND DATEADD(HH, -4, CONVERT(DATETIME, substring(DATE, 1, 4) + '-' + substring(DATE, 5, 2) + '-' + substring(DATE, 7, 2) + ' ' + substring(DATE, 10, 2) + ':' + substring(DATE, 12, 2) + ':' + substring(DATE, 14, 2) + '.' + substring(DATE, 16, 3))) > GETDATE() - 4
Order by Date DESC, RemovalPath DESC;
```

Comment: sergio It gives me this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Is it possible for you to remove the 7 microseconds digits in the time part of your code?